# Couldn't locate 'figures.py' in the app directory (Django-matplotlib integration)

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I did everything exactly as mentioned in this link:

https://django-matplotlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

When I go to the admin page and click on Add My Model. I get the error

```
ImportError at /admin/my_app/mymodel/add/

Couldn't locate 'figures.py' in the app directory.
```

figures.py is in the same directory as models.py as suggested in the documentation.

If anyone has tried to include matplotlib in django in this manner, I would like to know what I did wrong.

Beginner here. Please be patient.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I needed to install matplotlib in the active virtualenv of django as well, not just through normal Shell. So, I activated my virtualend and then installed matplotlib as well using pip install matplotlib. The figure shows now just as the documentation shows.